# Why does my Ember computed property on hasMany relationship not update?

Tags: ember.js, emberfire

I have an Ember Data model as:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  friends: DS.hasMany('friend',{async:true}),
  requestedFriendIds: Ember.computed('friends',function(){
    return this.get('friends').then(function(friends){
      return friends.filterBy('status','Requested').mapBy('id');
    });
  })
 });
```

I have a route setup that uses it:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params){
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      memberProfile:this.store.find('member-profile', params.memberprofile_id).then(function(memberProfile)
      {
        return Ember.RSVP.hash({
          requestedFriendIds:memberProfile.get('requestedFriendIds'),
          UserId:memberProfile.get('user.id'),
          Id:memberProfile.get('id')
        });
      }),
    });
   }
 });
```

},

And htmlbars that utilize the route model.  My computed property is always correctly called on a reload, but isn't refreshed on a user action 'Add Friend', which changes the store by adding a friend and the profile.friends' record like this:

```
actions:
{
  addFriend:function(profile_id,)
  {
    this.store.findRecord('member-profile',memberProfile).then(function(member){
      var friend = this.store.createRecord('friend',
      {
        member:member,
        status:'Requested',
        timestamp: new Date(),
      });
      friend.save();
      member.get('friends').pushObject(friend);
      member.save();
  }.bind(this));
}
```

}

Some notes:  I've tried the computed property on 'friends','friends.[]'.  My code base is Ember 2.0.1, with Ember.Data 1.13.12, and as such 'friends.@each' is deprecated.  The underlying data is correctly updated in the backing store (EmberFire).  I've debugged into EmberData and I see that the property changed notifications invalidation code is called.  This is only a selection of the code...

What am I missing...?  Is there a better way to approach this?

Comment: I believe you want to watch `friends.@each` on the CP.

Comment: @each is deprecated in Ember 2.*.  I'll update my question.

Comment: Watching only `friends.@each` isn't what it was designed for. It should be `friends.[]` for sure.

Comment: Please check my answer again. I've added another possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should watch `friends.[]` instead of only `friends`:

```
requestedFriendIds: Ember.computed('friends.[]',function(){
    return this.get('friends').then(function(friends){
      return friends.filterBy('status','Requested').mapBy('id');
    });
  })
```

And you could probably put your action in your route and manually refresh model (it might be issue with promise result not binding to changes in CP). So, **in your route:**

```
actions: {
  addFriend(profile_id) {
    this.store.findRecord('member-profile', memberProfile).then(member => {
      let friend = this.store.createRecord('friend',
      {
        member:member,
        status:'Requested',
        timestamp: new Date()
      });
      friend.save();
      member.get('friends').pushObject(friend);
      member.save();

      this.refresh();
    });
  }
}
```

The most important part is using [`this.refresh()` in Ember.Route](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_refresh).

Comment: Please check my answer again. I've added another possible solution.